# How to use docker compose for aws ecr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

Until now I had only the rails server and database but now I have added a few dependencies like sidekiq, redis and sneakers for rabbitmq. I want to use docker-compose. I have below dockerfile and docker-compose file.

Dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.2
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 registry.docker.com/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base
RUN export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git libpq-dev libvips pkg-config

WORKDIR /rails

ENV BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development"

RUN gem install foreman

FROM base as build
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

FROM base
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]
EXPOSE 3000


# Use Foreman to start processes defined in Procfile
# CMD ["foreman", "start"]
# CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    platform: linux/amd64
    command: ./bin/rails server
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=******
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - dbClusterIdentifier=*****
      - username=*****
      - password=*****
      - host=db
      - port=5432
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started

  db:
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - dbClusterIdentifier=<identifier>
      - username=<username>
      - password=<password>
      - host=db
      - port=5432
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 30

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    depends_on:
      - redis

  # sneakers:
  #   build: .
  #   command: "bundle exec rails sneakers:run"
  #   depends_on:
  #     - web
  #     - redis
  #     - sidekiq

volumes:
  pg_data:
  redis_data:
  bundle:
```

I was following below docker commands for pushing the image to aws ecr

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username <username> --password-stdin <ecr_path>
docker build -t <service_name> .
docker tag <service_name>:latest <ecr_path>/<service_name>:latest
docker push <ecr_path>/<service_name>:latest
```

How can i push the docker compose image now to aws ecr. Do you see any problem in the docker-compose.ymlor Dockerfile?

Comment: Docker compose would not be involved at all in pushing the image to ECR. You might build the docker image using `docker compose build` instead of `docker build` but after that, you would still push the image to ECR using the same `docker push` command that you had used before.

Comment: Make sure you delete the `volumes:` that replace parts of the image with local files or named volumes.  These won't be available in your remote environment.  The `docker tag; docker push` sequence you show looks correct, is there a specific problem you're having with it?